# Basic C# Calculator

Tags: c#, beginner, calculator

I am a beginner programmer, I decided to make this calculator program to test my knowledge on basic C# syntax, the code executes as intended, however I would like to shorten it to be more concise.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please select your first number: ");

double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please select your second number: ");

double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please choose the operation: "); 

var userInput = Console.ReadLine(); 

if (userInput == "+") 
{
    Console.WriteLine(numberOne + numberTwo);
}
else if (userInput == "-")
{
    Console.WriteLine(numberOne - numberTwo);
}
else if (userInput == "*")
{
    Console.WriteLine(numberOne * numberTwo);
}
else if (userInput == "/")
{
    Console.WriteLine(numberOne / numberTwo); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, please include the main class/function and imports so that people can just copy your code and compile it without having to add anything to it.

Comment: @slepic Using .NET 6, the code as-is can be copied/pasted and run without any changes.  I just launched a new project in VS, copied the code in the question, and ran it without issue.  Line 1 is the first `Console.WriteLine()`, and the last line in the file is line 28, the closing brace of the final `else if` block.  If OP is just starting with C#, it's likely that their file only contains what's shown in the question (and perhaps are not aware of namespaces, `public static void Main` etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is good, but there are a few improvements that you could make.

**Determining what operation your user wants.**

Instead of using `if/else`, I'd probably use a `switch/case` statement:

```
switch userInput
{
    case "+":
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + numberTwo);
        break;
    case "-":
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne - numberTwo);
        break;
    case "*":
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne * numberTwo);
        break;
    case "/":
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne / numberTwo);
        break;
}
```

**Error handling with user inputs**

I'd probably also put a `default` clause, just in case your user doesn't enter one of `+ - * /`:

```
switch userInput
{
    ...
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, unknown operation.");
        break;
}
```

I would also use a `try/catch` block for figuring out what `numberOne` and `numberTwo` are:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please select your first number: ");
    double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    
    Console.WriteLine("Please select your second number: ");
    double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid number."); 
}
```

You might also want to check whether `numberTwo` is not zero when dividing:

```
switch userInput
{
    ...
    case "/":
        if numberTwo == 0
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, cannot divide by zero.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numberOne / numberTwo);
        }

        break;
}
```

Comment: And while you're at it (_it_ being "error handling") you may want to check that `numberTwo` is not zero when dividing.

Comment: As an alternative for the `try/catch`, you could also use `double.TryParse`. That would also simplify making the app loop until valid numbers are entered.

Comment: @CompuChip, is this what you mean (I have added a section).

Comment: Don't use try catch for converting numbers. Use [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse) instead. Try catch will have an impact on performance in duration each time the users enters an invalid number.

Comment: Also, there's no need to duplicate operations (`WriteLine`). Logic should only modify the data. So create a `result` variable. Modify it as many times as you need. Print it once.

Comment: *check that numberTwo is not zero when dividing*  =>  Catch the error at entry or at execution ( pressing '=') ?  ->  Catching during execution future-proofs the code.  Adding operator chaining (3+1-2) and parentheses (operation precedence) will likely break existing code. You can't predict what the user will enter next or how a not-yet-completed expression will parse.